# setTimeout for whole site, not just one page

Tags: javascript, html

How would I use setTimeout() - or any other javascript method - to call a function when the user had been on my website for 45 seconds.

I was using the below:

```
setTimeout(function(){ ....code.... }, 45000);
```

But if the user navigated off the page and onto another page on the site before 45 seconds, the timer was reset.

I'd like the setTimeout to apply to the time the user landed on the first page, regardless of what page they are on now.

I will be including this javascript on every page on the site.

Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't work like that. You'll have to start the timer on every individual page. You can save the time the visitor first arrived in local storage and then calculate the appropriate difference.

Comment: You can use local storage to store any sort of data between page visits. You can do it like: localStorage.setItem('key','value'); The better option would be to have server side timeout calculations.

Comment: You can get idea from this option https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_coming_soon_js

Comment: Joey's comment make sense.   Maybe look at SignalR.  See https://www.intertech.com/Blog/SignalR-Real-time-Web-Made-Easy/ and https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to store the timestamp to `localStorage` when user comes to your page and start a timer using `setTimeOut` and listen to `onbeforeUnlaod` event when user goes from your site.

Again when user comes back query the localStorage for `lastTime` and reinit the timer.

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u8jn3xkh/1/)

```
var your_delay = 5*1000;
window.init= function(){
    var start = localStorage.getItem('start');
    var end = new Date().getTime();
    if(start){
         if(end-start<your_delay)
           setTimeout(action,your_delay-(end-start));
    }else{
       setTimeout(action,your_delay);
    }
}
window.onbeforeunlaod = function(){
      /* Send the timer to server if you want it to be consistant across browser */
}


window.action = function(){
     alert("Hi");
}

init();
```

Comment: What exactly do you do in `onbeforeUnlaod`…?

Comment: @Seabizkit Doesn't make a lot of sense if you're storing the timestamp there so it's available on the next page…

Comment: @deceze so when you close your browser... with 5 secs to go.... when you open it again on the site it will fire your function in 5 secs instead of 45.... do you follow now...

Comment: dont remove on page nav but remove when ur site url is closed.

Comment: @Seabizkit `onbeforeonload` fires every time you move from one page to another, not just when you close the browser…

Comment: @Seabizkit yes, there is not much to do here in onbefore unload unless you want to do something like how long user was on your page for analytics and send information to server.

Answer (score 2):

Just add that javascript file to all the pages with the `setTimeout` function. It will reset automatically when the user goes to other pages:

`setTimeout(() => { ... }, 45e3)`

If I understood correctly you also want to save the time IF the user is more than 45 seconds on the page. Then use `localStorage` for that. First get the time he has been on the site with a date object:

```
let timer = new Date()
```

Then save the difference on `localStorage` (in milliseconds):

```
localStorage.setItem("Time on site", new Date().getTime() - timer.getTime())
```

Whenever you want to access that time use:

```
localStorage.getItem("Time on site")
```

Execute the timer when the page loads inside:

```
let timer
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    timer = new Date()
})
```